# How do I see which kernel patches are included in an Ubuntu kernel image?

Tags: kernel, packaging, source-code, source-packages

When I search for the kernel images on either [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy) or the [Ubuntu Package Library](https://packages.ubuntu.com/), the kernel changelogs only show something like:

```
linux-meta (5.15.0.47.47) jammy; urgency=medium

  * Bump ABI 5.15.0-47

 -- Stefan Bader <email address hidden>  Wed, 10 Aug 2022 10:00:45 +0200
```

How do I see the complete list of patches included in the various kernel images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see which patches are included, you have to find the Ubuntu source files for the particular kernel package - and NOT for the metapackage.

For Generic and Raspberry Pi kernels respectively, the sources packages are here:

- [Source Package: linux (5.15.0-47.51)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/jammy-updates/linux)
- [Source Package: linux-raspi (5.15.0-1014.16)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/jammy-updates/linux-raspi)

When clicking on the *"Ubuntu Changelog"* in the right-hand menu, you get the complete changelog file with all kernel patches included - and with reference to the mainline kernels that include the patches as well.

- [Changelog: linux (5.15.0-47.51) jammy](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux/linux_5.15.0-47.51/changelog)
- [Changelog: linux-raspi (5.15.0-1014.16) jammy](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-raspi/linux-raspi_5.15.0-1014.16/changelog)